# How can I force to connect to different server behind a load balancer?

Tags: c#, iis, webclient, load-balancing

I'm going to request some IIS web server through (for instance) WebClient for some website. IIS has two (or more) instances and load balancer decides which will be used for handling the request. Usually if the connection is established the particular server is assigned to response further requests. Is there any way to force load balancer to connect with different server? Is there any method of any class in .NET to do it or at least to determine which web server is responding?

I'm asking because I need to connect to all of the servers behind the load balancer and check downloaded content.

Answer (score 1):

No, since the load balancer has to decide before your code even had a chance of being executed on the web server.

It would be pretty hazardous if an outsider could influence the choice of the load balancer; DoS attacks would be much easier.

Comment: That's bad. Any tricks like refreshing IP in case of using DHCP? Do you know how long load balancer can "stick" me to the particular server? (Yest I know it makes little sense in case of 3 or more servers but I have two and guaranteed difference of content, even if it sounds strange).

Comment: "refreshing IP in case of using DHCP" <- I'm sorry, but this sounds like you have dangerously little understanding of IP networks.

Comment: Ha, nice retort. You're right, I have little understanding of it.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways.

1. You can temporarily pause one of the servers using the Load
   Balancer.   That works well for delivery testing or development
   environments.   As a rule I would say that should be required when
   doing any delivery tests otherwise you never really know if you got
   both servers correct.
2. You can use a Web Proxy to hit your web server from another
   location.  Depending upon the Load Balancer setup your odds are
   50/50 that you will get the same server or the other.

One example of a Web Proxy is: https://nordvpn.com/web-proxy/

To help in debugging I try to make a point of putting something unique on each server so that I know which one I am hitting.  This might be a small clue in a page footer or something similar.